# Regular expression to convert PDF URL to an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, regex

I know I should dedicate time to learn regular expressions but meanwhile help me please.

With javascript I want to convert this:

```
 http://www.url.pdf (or https://)
```

to

```
<iframe src="http://www.url.pdf" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
(https?:\/\/\S*?\.pdf)
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/vJ2aY9

Will convert:

- `http://www.url.pdf`
- `https://www.otherurl.pdf`

To:

- `<iframe src="http://www.url.pdf" width="500" height="400"></iframe>`
- `<iframe src="https://www.otherurl.pdf" width="500" height="400"></iframe>`

...by way of the capture group and backreference `$1`.

---

**Footnote:** generally speaking, you should show at least a minimal effort when posting a question. A good resource to learn about regular expressions is http://regular-expressions.info, or you can even use regex101 to play around and learn what each special character does.

Comment: Thank you @remus this what I needed. Sounds silly now viewing the solution, now it seems easy but I was playing some time and I can't find it, I was near but It didn't work. It's clear, I have to learn regular expressions NOW, thank you for your resources.